# How to include "company health metrics" on resume

Tags: resume

I've been wanting to revamp my resume and I'm curious about the best way to include numbers for company performance and growth. Obviously, I can't take sole credit for my previous companies hiring more, or growing in revenue, but I think still this could be helpful.

**What is the best way to include company metrics on a resume? Do some metrics matter more than others to employers?**

Comment: Did you influence any of those metrics directly in a way you can prove?

Comment: Can you tell us some of the metrics you worked on ? Then, we will provide inputs.

Comment: Once you're at your new job, do you expect to leave as soon as you make a positive impact on relevant metrics?

Answer (score 11):

Unless you *directly* contributed *significantly* to those metrics (e.g. you were the CMO and you are quoting marketing metrics), do **not** put them on your resume: I don't care about how well the company that you happened to work for did, I care about what *you* can do.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best way to include company metrics on a resume? Do some
> metrics matter more than others to employers?

Don't take credit for something you didn't do. Company metrics are not your metrics. The company could have performed wonderfully at the same time you performed poorly.

And without a huge amount of context, which cannot be effectively conveyed in a resume, metrics mean nothing at all to most hiring managers.

Leave company metrics off of your resume. Include personal accomplishments instead.

If for some reason you decide to include any metric on your resume, be prepared to fully explain how much specific individual credit you can claim for that metric, and why.

Answer (score 4):

Are you the CEO? Another C-level? If so, just include the metrics, you know the drill by now.

Are you a rank-and-file engineer? Then don't overthink it.

Pick one metric you feel you had been a part of delivering. For instance, "Launched MVP in 3 months" is one. Hiring more is a relevant metric if you are/were in HR.

In short:

- Describe the company in terms of its end state when you left.
- Include metrics for anything you were significantly contributing to as your achievements. Yes, your recruiter and HM will know they weren't solely yours. They'll ask you about your part.